# sublime ctags configuration to include tag files in some directories

Tags: tags, include, ctags

I would like to include some tag files from some directories to my project and I use Sublime 3.

I edited "Ctags.sublime-settings-User" like this,but doesn't work:

```
// Paths to additional tag files to include in tag search. This is a list
// of items in the form [["language", "platform"], "path"]
"extra_tag_paths": [[["source.c++", "linux"], "/home/.../OpenSim/tags"]],

// Additional tag files to search
"extra_tag_files": ["tags"]
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the path at the "extra_tag_files" command and NOT at the "extra_tag_paths" - as it actually says in the Default Settings of CTags! Like this:

```
 "extra_tag_files": ["tags", "/home/maria/.../OpenSim/tags"]
```